# Connecting AWS to your iOS code base for authentication

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have used this GitHub as a base: https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth

The LambdaAuth project worked well out of the box and I learned how to set up Cognito, Identity pools, Lambda, and DynamoDB tables. So currently I have everything setup on the AWS side of things. I have tested the Lambda functions and checked them with DynamoDB tables and all is well.

On the iOS side of things, I have my sign up and register view controllers created and I have added the AWS iOS SDK and all of its frameworks.

UPDATE:
 I have Lamdba functions that check usernames and passwords and add them to the database if they don't exist.

I have also created in Identity Pool which has the unauth and auth roles.  After using Lambda to verify that the username is new and creates an entry in the db, then I switch from the unauth role to the auth role.

At that point I want to access the db and s3 for only that user.

I am wondering how to get started.

What are the next steps to connect ios to aws? The mobile hub demo is awful and doesn't give great examples.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what you're trying to do? What you mean by 'connect iOS to AWS'? Also, have you seen the new Cognito User Pools service that just launched? It might be easier for you to integrate.

Comment: Updated with some notes above. Trying to figure out what code to add into my ios to make it work. Do I use Lambda first before cognito, like the lambda worker? (new to aws as I was from parse)

Comment: Following up below in an answer

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Learning AWS is slow but nice to have people helping

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm no expert on LambdAuth, but I believe it's based on Cognito's developer authenticated identities feature, using the GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity API. What that means is once you log in, you should be able to get a token and an identity id back, at which point you can pick up from the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html).

Have you checked out Cognito [User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html)? It was designed to help with this exact problem, it's a full-fledged, scalable user directory that might be easier to onboard with as a ex-Parser.

Comment: Yeah you are correct about Lambda auth. I will look into the User Pools as I have not yet. I will test this stuff out tonight.